# Biopython Package not recognized even when installed

Tags: python, pip, installation, biopython

I ran `pip3 install biopython` and it seemed to have been installed correctly

[image]

But when I try to run it in ipython or python3 for example

[image]

I'm quite confused because if I do the same thing with numpy or sklearn it works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: At a _guess_; you're installing into the system 3.5 version of Python, rather than Anaconda running python 3.6. You can try `conda install biopython`.

Comment: @roganjosh good catch, but it looks like no matter what version I install it doesn't run correctly

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install biopython`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your environment you are using to run Python (second image) is using the Anaconda Python Distribution.

When you are installing using the command in the first image you are installing in the Python3 environment but not in the Anaconda Distribution environment.

Try running the following command to install the package in Anaconda:

```
conda install biopython
```

Comment: yeah, but i don't want to install to anaconda, I want it in my python 3 environment. That is what my VS Code is set up in.

Comment: @AndreFu But the `python3` is currently pointing to anaconda's version of python3.